# Recursive type definitions in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, recursion

I have encountered what would seem like an extremely simple issue to solve, and I think I may be missing something.

The program crashes when attempting to create a recursive variable (?) with the typed to a class while being a member of the said class. For example:

```
class A {
    var x: A

    init() {
        x = A()
    }
}
```

Checking the crash log suggests a recursion of sorts, with `init()` being called infinitely.

Is there a proper method/syntax to solve this sort of problem, given that I need the variable `x` to be typed to class `A`, and the initializer must initialize variable `x` to class `A`?

Comment: A normal endless recursion that causes stack overflow. Nothing wrong here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious that at some step you should left property `x` uninitialized. So, thats better to declare it as `Optional`, and initialize it after instance was created:

```
class A {
    var x: A?
}

let mainObject = A()
let nestedObject = A()
mainObject.x = nestedObject
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but i think you are looking for this

```
class A {
    var x: A?

    init() {
    }

    anothermethod() {
       x = A()
    }
}
```

and you can call this method like

```
    let a = A()
    a.anothermethod()
```